# How to send objects to a function properly?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, panel

So I have a class called "Screen" and function:

```
void closeAllTabs(Panel leftTab, Panel rightTab);
```

I am sending 2 objects of type panel there.
Further down in my main class, I try to call the function like this:

```
Screen scr;
scr.closeAllTabs(leftMainTab, rightMainTab);
```

But when I try to call this function and send the panels there, I get an error.

C++ function cannot be called with the given argument list            argument types are: (System::Windows::Forms::Panel ^, System::Windows::Forms::Panel ^)            object type is: ProjectName::Screen

Comment: The error is reasonably clear? You need to change the parameters to match the type of the arguments by adding `^` to make them refs

Comment: @AlanBirtles like scr.closeAllTabs(&leftMainTab, &rightMainTab) or scr.closeAllTabs(^leftMainTab, ^rightMainTab)

Comment: No, you need to change the function, I've not used c++-cli for years so i could be wrong

Comment: @AlanBirtles than I rewrite the function to closeAllTabs(Panel ^leftTab, Panel ^rightTab) then the error is gone. Thank you and sorry for obvious question I don't know much about passing arguments by reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I should have add reference

```
        void closeAllTabs(Panel ^leftTab, Panel ^rightTab);
```

Thank

> the error is reasonably clear? You need to change the parameters to match the type of the arguments by adding ^ to make them refs – Alan Birtles

apologize for immediately writing here without examining the error :P